# How to parse this type of data ios sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [parse UTF-8 JSON ios sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334675/parse-utf-8-json-ios-sdk)

```
[4,"1.0",1347139911696]
[0,"Neathouse Place","58226","STBC",154,"L",51.495322,-0.141808]
[0,"Vauxhall Bridge Rd / Victoria Stn","59516","STBC",160,"Z9",51.495931,-0.142216]
[0,"VICTORIA, VAUXHALL BRIDGE ROAD (EAST)",null,null,0,null,51.495839,-0.142119]
[0,"Vauxhall Bridge Rd / Victoria Stn","54249","STBC",256,"M",51.496573,-0.141354]
```

How to parse this type of data.

check this [link](http://countdown.api.tfl.gov.uk/interfaces/ura/instant_V1?Circle=51.49598,-0.14091,100&StopPointState=0&ReturnList=StopCode1,StopPointName,Bearing,StopPointIndicator,StopPointType,Latitude,Longitude).

It is UTF-8 JSON data type according to service provider. If its not then please tell me which type of data is it and how to parse it.

please help me out.

thanks.

Comment: You have now posted the identical question three times!

Comment: thanks for giving me such information without helping..really appreciated.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat , i tried to parse using various json parser [SBJSON, JSONKIT, etc] but no luck. and i'm also thinking which type of data is it?

Comment: @MartinR is trying to help you use this site correctly, but you are just being sarcastic back. This is a community, people come here to help, but acting that will get you nowhere.

Comment: @user1657262: Actually I have given an answer to your original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to realize is that your data is actually 5 separate but valid `JSON` arrays. `JSON` can be validated at [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com).

To make something useful from them you must split your response by lines. You can use the newline character as a delimiter.

```
// stringWithContentsOfURL: used for demonstration
NSURL *sourceURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://countdown.api.tfl.gov.uk/interfaces/ura/instant_V1?Circle=51.49598,-0.14091,100&StopPointState=0&ReturnList=StopCode1,StopPointName,Bearing,StopPointIndicator,StopPointType,Latitude,Longitude"];
NSString *actualResponse = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:sourceURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray *individualJSONArrays = [actualResponse componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

You now have an `NSArray` with 5 valid `JSON` `NSStrings`. You can either deal with any one of them, or convert them all to `NS`-Class objects by enumerating like so:

```
NSMutableArray *jsonObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSString *jsonString in individualJSONArrays) {
    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
    if (jsonArray){
        [jsonObjects addObject:jsonArray];
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@",jsonObjects);
```

You now have an `NSArray` filled with `NSArrays`.